# Exit(0) not ending the programme

Tags: c++, shell, fork, exit-code

I am making a shell and trying to understand the function of fork it (Only the code with issue is shown below).

However, After adding `fork();` my shell is not exiting with the command ***exit***. I know I can use `kill(pid, SIGKILL)` to achieve this but I do not want to show any exit status. I think `exit(0);` should work without the need of `kill(pid, SIGKILL)`.

A simple explanation with the code would help a lot.

**Update:** I want to accept continuous commands until exit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct cmds{
  string cmd;
} cmds;
bool operator<(cmds &as1, cmds &bs1){
  return as1.durr<bs1.durr;
}


int main() {
  vector <cmds> lst;
  cmds ant;
  string cmd;
  pid_t pid = fork() ;
  while (1){
    if(pid==0){
      cout<<"$>";
      getline(cin,cmd);
      ant.cmd=cmd;
      string comd;
      for(int i=0;i<cmd.length();i++){
        if(cmd[i]!=' ')
          comd+=cmd[i];
      }
      if(comd=="exit"){
        exit(0);
      }
      else{
        char s[256]="";
        for (int i=0; i<cmd.length(); i++) 
          s[i]=cmd[i];
      }
      lst.push_back(ant);
    }
    else
      wait(NULL);
  }
}
```

---

```
**Expected output** - //The shell should end without any cout or exit status//

**Actual output** - //The shell does not end and you can type anything and enter and continue - however no '$' is present and you cannot use any shell commands//
```

Apologies for any messy writing - The new UI for writing questions is hard to use.

Comment: Any particular reason I got downvoted and how to ensure that never happens?

Comment: You should try running your program through a debugger.

Comment: I tried the debugger but still was not able to fix the issue. :(

Comment: What state did the debugger say your program was in?

Comment: it said: exit status -1

Comment: I'm talking about examining the state of the stack after you interrupt the program in its bad state

Comment: Your parent process - what is it good for except to `wait()` for the child process again and again (ignoring the fact that the child can terminate only once). Your `fork()` seems to be a bit useless as it is.

Comment: @Scheff system(); does contain exit as a command.

Comment: That's true. But AFAIK, `system()` does block until requested command has been terminated (if it doesn't fail to start). I once looked for source code and found a combination of `fork()`, `exec()`, and `wait()` in its implementation. Btw. you check for `"exit"` (and bail out) before you call `system()`. So, what has `system()` to do with input `"exit"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent process is stuck in `while(1)` loop. Add `break;` line after `wait(NULL);`.

Comment: I want to accept continous command until exit. break; will stop it after one command.

Comment: @UtsoRoy Only your child process should be in `while(1)` loop.

Comment: How to make only the child process in the while(1) loop?

Comment: _How to make only the child process in the while(1) loop?_ `int pid = fork(); if (pid == -1) { /* fork failed */ exit(-1); } else if (pid == 0) { /* child */ while (1) { /* ... */ } } else { /* parent */ wait(pid); }`

Comment: @UtsoRoy Have you tried inserting a line with `break;` as the answer suggests?

Comment: @Scheff error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
 else { /* parent */ wait(pid); }

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin yes - break; will stop it after one command.  - I have updated the question.

Comment: @UtsoRoy Sorry, my fault. `wait()` wants address of status variable. (I confused with `waitpid()`. I just sketched the code without caring about details too much.)  `wait(NULL)` was the better choice.